# Aligning div items with flexbox

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble aligning multiple div items when using flex box. mainly for div id= 'flow'. I want the content header and content itself to be aligned vertically while being presented in rows/ below is how it should look. Tried using justify content center and even tried wrapping it multiple ways but since they are separate entities they do align vertically only horizontally

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Pacific Trails Resort :: Activities </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pacific.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrapper {
            display: grid;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            min-width: 960px;
            max-width: 2048px;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333333;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #90c7e3;
            background: linear-gradient(white ,#90c7e3);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        header {
            background-color: #002171;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background-image: url(sunset.jpg);
            background-position: right;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            text-align: center;
        }

        header ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        h1 {
            padding-top: .5em;
            padding-bottom: .5em;
            margin: 0;
        }


        h2 {
            color: #1976D2;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px #CCCCCC;
        }

        h3{
            color: #00003;
        }
        nav {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
        }

        nav ul{
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

        }

        nav li{
        list-style: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #00008b;
        }

        nav a {
            list-style-type: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 8px;
            color: #002171;
        }

        ul{
            list-style-image: url(marker.gif);
        }

        dt{
            color: #002171;
        }

        main{
            padding-top: 1px;
            padding-right: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            padding-left: 20px;
            display: block;
        }

        .contact{
            font-size: 90%;
        }

        footer{
            font-size: 75%;
            font-style:italic;
            padding: 2em;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #homehero{
            height: 300px;
            background-image: url(coast.jpg);
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        #yurthero{
            height: 300px;
            background-image: url(yurt.jpg);
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;

        }

        #trailhero{
            height: 300px;
            background-image: url(trail.jpg);
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;

        }

        .Resort{
            color: #1976D2;
            font-weight:bold;
        }

        @media (min-width: 600px){

            nav ul{
                flex-direction: row;
                flex:none;
                justify-content: space-around;
                border: none;
            }

            nav li{
                border-bottom: none;
                display: inline;
                text-align: center;
            }

            nav a {
                margin-right: 2em;
                margin-left; 2em;
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: 10px;
            }

            #flow{
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                flex: 1;
                justify: center;
                align-items: center;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>Pacific Trails Resort</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="yurts.html">Yurts</a>
            <a href="activities.html">Activities</a>
            <a href="index.html">Reservations</a>
        </nav>
        <div id="trailhero">

        </div>
        <main>
            <h2>Activities at Pacific Trails</h2>

            <div id="flow">
                <h3>Hiking</h3>
                <p>Pacific Trails Resort has 5 miles of hiking trails and is adjacent to a state park. Go alone or join one of our guided hikes </p>
                <h3>Kayaking</h3>
                <p>Ocean kayaks are available for guest use</p>
                <h3>Bird Watching</h3>
                <p>While anytime is a good time for bird watching at Pacific Trails, we offer guided birdwatching trips at sunrise several times a week.</p>
          </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <small>
                <i>Copy right &copy; 2022 Pacific Trails Resort</i><br />
                <a href="mailto:davilaco@asu.edu"> davilaco@asu.edu</a>
            </small>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[what is should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnctY.png)

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made some changes to your code by wrapping each content in a `div` and giving it class `card`. I also corrected your `#flow` styling where you put `justify` instead of `justify-content`.

```
<main>
   <div class='title'>
     <h2>Activities at Pacific Trails</h2>
   </div>
   <div id="flow">
     <div class='card'>
       <h3>Hiking</h3>
       <p>Pacific Trails Resort has 5 miles of hiking trails and is adjacent to a state park. Go alone or join one of our guided hikes </p>
     </div>
     <div class='card'>
       <h3>Kayaking</h3>
       <p>Ocean kayaks are available for guest use</p>
     </div>
     <div class='card'>
       <h3>Bird Watching</h3>
       <p>While anytime is a good time for bird watching at Pacific Trails, we offer guided birdwatching trips at sunrise several times a week. </p>
     </div>
  </main>
```

CSS:

```
.title {
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
 }
 #flow{
   display: flex;
   flex: 1;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
 }
 .card{
   text-align: center;
   width: 500px;
 }
```

[Here's how it looks like](https://codepen.io/pen/)

Answer (score 0):

Inside #flow you want 3 columns, instead you have six items. Why not wrap each heading-paragraph pair inside a div?

```
<div id="flow">
     <div class='column'>
            <h3>Hiking</h3>
            <p>Pacific Trails Resort has 5 miles of hiking trails and is 
              adjacent to a state park. Go alone or join one of our guided hikes </p>
     </div>
     <div class='column'>
            <h3>Kayaking</h3>
            <p>Ocean kayaks are available for guest use</p>
     </div>
     <div class='column'>
            <h3>Bird Watching</h3>
            <p>While anytime is a good time for bird watching at Pacific Trails, we offer guided birdwatching trips at sunrise several times a week. 
           </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

From there styling should be straight forward

```
#flow{
display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.column{
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  max-width: 20em;
}
```

Example in [codepen here](https://codepen.io/shawncaza/pen/zYjexyJ).

But if you want all 3 columns to always be the same width, it might make more sense to use display:grid on #flow.